# "Multiply" (Concatenate) Text Columns in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate

Simple question that I can't seem to find a solution for. I have text data in two columns like

| Name | Num |
| --- | --- |
| a | 1 |
| b | 2 |

and I would like to produce a single formula if possible to output a 3rd column

| Name&Num |
| --- |
| a1 |
| a2 |
| b1 |
| b2 |

Really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
=index(flatten(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")&transpose(filter(B2:B,B2:B<>""))))
```

[image]

First we transpose B2:B, then we perform a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) with the `&` operator and finally we [flatten](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/10307761?hl=en) the output.